# CentOS 7 VNC users dont share desktop session

Tags: centos, vnc, desktop-environment

I installed VNC server on a CentOS machine. I set up a user, and then enabled the VNC server for them on startup following these steps: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-remote-access-for-the-gnome-desktop-on-centos-7. I can successfully log into the machine over VNC, but it appears that the VNC users are not sharing the same session... as if I log into the physical machine and start up a process, when the VNC connection is made, nothing is active on the desktop at all. What did I do wrong? I need VNC to allow users to log in and remotely debug software which may or may not have been started by someone logged into the physical machine

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the expert, but I have a friend who uses ssh to easily access my machines, one I give him a login. It's one of many way, but it has worked for me. I don't think it's as secure as VPN, but it has worked out, with no incident so far. He does have a better vantage point to catch unsavory activities. It's not my field, but like I said, it seems to work well.

Comment: I appreciate the response... I ended up uninstalling tigervnc entirely from the machine, and used the built in vino server... the only issue is that I  had to disable encryption on the server to support connections from an ultra vnc viewer, due to type 18 not being supported.

Answer (score 0):

You could use x11vnc for this.
As Root (sudo -i):

```
yum install x11vnc
x11vnc -storepasswd /etc/x11vnc.pass

printf '[Unit]\nDescription="x11vnc"\nRequires=display-manager.service\nAfter=multi-user.target\n\n' > /etc/systemd/system/x11vnc.service
printf '[Service]\nExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -xkb -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -auth guess -display :0 -forever -shared -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc.pass -usepw \nExecStop=/usr/bin/killall x11vnc\nRestart=always\nRestartSec=150ms\n\n' >> /etc/systemd/system/x11vnc.service
printf '[Install]\nWantedBy=multi-user.target\n\n' >> /etc/systemd/system/x11vnc.service
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable x11vnc.service
systemctl start x11vnc.service
```

That will share the primary display with anyone who connects and knows the x11 password you set.

```
less /etc/systemd/system/x11vnc.service
```

Look at the ExecStart line to see what arguments it is using, those are documented here: http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/x11vnc_opts.html